# OpenPrimaryTab in service console opens in same tab

Tags: apex, visualforce, console

I have tried by giving id as null but still on click existing tabs get refreshed.

```
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null, pageName, true,'xyz',null,this.xyz, 'abz');
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the salesforce console integration toolkit guide, openPrimaryTab() method takes 6 parameters, whereas you are passing seven. Please verify the same.

> sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(id:String, url:URL, active:Boolean, (optional)tabLabel:String, (optional)callback:Function, (optional)name)

I tried the same example given [in this link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_openprimarytab.htm) and the tab opens as a primary tab.

Also, if the tab is already open, then Salesforce console prevents opening duplicate tabs.

Comment: When quoting documentation, it is best to post a link to it.

Comment: Your link is broken. *"Sorry, the document you are looking for doesn't exist or could not be retrieved."*

Comment: tried that also but looks like null is also considered as ID.
Getting exception "openPrimaryTab: Opening a duplicate tab is not allowed."